# Does the white wire carry any electrons?

Tags: current, mains, colour-coding

I don't understand the neutral in 110V. Does it carry any current? Does a load like a light reduce the current?

Comment: Hi Rao, welcome to eesx. Please note that your question is quite poor in my opinion, understanding what you are asking is quite difficult and your question might be deleted. Try to improve it, please.

Comment: Neutral is called neutral because it is connected to a rod hammered into the earth. But it does carry current, just like the line or hot wire. The currents are equal unless there is some kind of fault causing current to flow to ground without going through the neutral. Ground Fault Interrupts will detect this fault current and trip. The details of how neutral is connected to ground need to be managed by knowledgeable people. It should only be connected in one place. Never connect neutral to ground inside of an appliance or whatever.

Comment: neutral is (maybe) connected to ground in the transformer cabin and is not guaranteed to be at ground potential, quite near possibly but not at it. at least in Italy.

Comment: Yeah. Technically, current cannot flow in a wire unless there is a small voltage from end to end. So there will always be some potential between neutral and ground except at the bonding location (assuming there is one, which in the US there always will be, somewhere).

Comment: Noo...absolutelly NO. There is no racism in electricity!! Both share the work equally

Comment: I'm assuming that the question if posed in better English would read more like: 
"I don't understand why neutral is used in 110v systems, does it carry any current, does a load like a light reduce the current?"
Is this what you are asking Rao ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this needs a simple explanation:

Current is the flow of charge, and charge is something that is always conserved*. It does not appear or vanish.  In metal wires, the charge is carried by electrons, particles that can move around.

Voltage is the force applied to the charge to move somewhere.

Between the two wires, there is a voltage, i.e. a force which causes the charges to flow from the one wire to the other - if there is a way.

**So yes, the current flows out from the one wire and into the other.**

If you connect any load, it has a resistance, which causes something like friction to the charge:

A high resistance causes high friction and so slowly moving charge or a low current. If you increase the voltage, there is more force driving the charge, and the current is higher.

The neutral on 110V is connected to earth, i.e. that planet we are living on. So there is no voltage between earth (your floor) and the neutral wire. The other wire is 'hot', you can measure 110V between earth and this wire. So don't touch!

So, this was very simple, I hope not too simple.

In reality, thinks are a bit more complicated. For example the voltage is alternating, i.e. it changes between pushing / pulling the charge 50 to 60 times per second.

---

*) Positive charge is attracted by negative, and if they meet together, hey can sum up to zero. And you can separate positive and negative charges in a neutral material. But you can not just create positive charge without creating the same amount of negative...

Answer (score 1):

In a single phase 110VAC system, Line and Neutral are connected in series with the source and the load, so they all (Line and Neutral and the source and the load) carry the same current.

The current and its direction will vary directly with the source voltage and its sign, and inversely with the load impedance/resistance according to Ohm's law, \$ \ \ I = \frac{E}{R},\  \$ as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

EMField and sweber's answers are good but I wanted to supplement those a little:

> **Is the white wire carrying any electrons**

All metal wires "carry" an unimaginably vast number of electrons at all times. A tiny proportion of those are what we call "free electrons" because they are relatively mobile. This tiny proportion is still unimaginably vast. If you connect *both* ends of the wire to a voltage source (like a battery) you will cause the free electrons to very very slowly drift along the wire.

> **I don't understand why neutral in 110v , does it carry any current,**

Electric current is electric charges flowing around a circuit. This means that as well as a path away from the voltage source, there has to be a return path that completes the circuit. In typical AC mains, the "neutral" wire provides the return path. The direction of AC current reverses around a hundred times each second - so the term "return path" is somewhat notional. The important part is that there must be a complete circuit, like a circle. The current is the same at  every position around a simple circuit.

The charge flowing into a load every moment is the same as the charge flowing out of it.

> **does the load like the light reduce the current**

It depends what you compare it with and how you use the word load. If you unscrewed the light bulb, there would be no current anywhere because there is a gap in the circuit. We say that removing the light-bulb has broken the circuit. In the same way, pressing a light switch will make a gap in the circuit and stop any current flowing.

If you replace a 40W light-bulb with a 100W light bulb, the current will be higher. We say the 100W light bulb has less resistance.

If you replace the light-bulb with a copper wire, the current will be so much higher that it will heat and melt the wire, burn anyone holding the wire and perhaps burn down the house. We say the copper wire has very low resistance - nearly no resistance at all.

So current depends on the resistance of the load. a gap has a very very high resistance, a copper wire has a very low resistance (compared to a light bulb).

Answer (score 0):

If one connects a 50W light  bulb to a house receptacle in the usual way I=W/V, say120/50=6 amps used. These amps flow in through the black wire and out through the white wire. But the voltage in the white wire is 0 as 120V has been dissapated in the light  bulb.  There has to be some voltage to push amps out as amps are measured in coulombs/sec.  Therefore one must think of the the circuit as originating at the main box so that there are 2 resistors, the bulb and the copper wire.  A table gives 12ga Cu wire resistance as 1.6 ohms/1000 ft. So 500ft gives  V=IR .8x6=4.8V which seemsto be enough to get the coulombs moving.  The difficulty would be in measuring this because back to the box is as long for the voltmeter as the wire. I think you would haveto drive a rod into the earth at the bulb.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine that we have a water tank and it connect with pipe and this pipe used to let water to flow . 
Water tank is voltage 
Pipe is the nutral wire 
So water in the tank with out pipe water will not flow 
Same thing in electricity with out nutral wire current will not flow in the circuit.
But in power we use closed circuit to let current flow in the circuit . 
To get 110V we need one phase and one nutral wire 
If there is any mistake please correct me

Comment: This analogy breaks down for several reasons: (1) You have no load. (2) You have no return pipe and that is the essential idea you need to explain for the question "_... why neutral in 110v , does it carry any current?_" Welcome to EE.SE.